# Getting the bad exception error on multiple button clicks

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

We have functionality of Like, Dislike and Comment. Whenever any user click on Like button more time then it shows Exc_Bad_Access[Code=1] error. Below is the part in the code where i am getting this error.

```
-(IBAction)sendLike:(id)sender{
    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
    if(!btn.tag)
    {
        btn.tag=0;
    }
    postCell *curCell=(postCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:btn.tag inSection:0]];
    user *myUser = [[[user alloc] init] autorelease];
    if([myUser likeObjectByID:[[[self.thePosts objectAtIndex:[(UIButton *) sender tag]] theData] objectForKey:@"itemID"]]){
        curCell.myASB.likeCount += 1;
        curCell.myASB.canLike=YES;
        [[[self.thePosts objectAtIndex:curCell.myIndex] theData] setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"] forKey:@"canLike"];
        NSString *tempCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", curCell.myASB.likeCount];

        [[[self.thePosts objectAtIndex:curCell.myIndex] theData] setObject:tempCount forKey:@"likes"];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Post your code on GitHub first or give more details otherwise there is no way to understand your situation

Comment: try setting exclusiveTouch to true

Comment: Try updating your project to use ARC.

Answer (score -3):

Try using the try - catch - finally in the code.
Maybe it will keep the app running.

```
@try {
        //Here write the code which you want to run,
        //In your case add the button action code here.
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception At: %s %d %s %s %@", __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FUNCTION__,exception);

        //Here you can put some alert view to notify the user, that something went wrong.
        //This is not compulsary.
    }
    @finally {
    }
```